# Slots and Dynamic Components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

It's an exercise from a Vue.js course I'm enrolled into. The aim is to get comfortable with the Vue.js features [Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) and [Dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components). By clicking on the buttons one shall be able to change the currently selected and rendered component.

With green button clicked:

[image: Screenshot of the App 1]

With the red button clicked:

[image]

The four main files with the styling where provided by the instructor. I had to write the JavaScript code.

```js
// -- App.vue ------------------------------------------------------------
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h2>Currently active component: {{ selected }}</h2>
                <br>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="onClick($event, 'blue')">Load Blue Template</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success" @click="onClick($event, 'green')">Load Green Template</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="onClick($event, 'red')">Load Red Template</button>
                <hr>
                <component :is="selected">
                    <h1 slot="blue-headline">Nicht von im verschwand so deiner und weiter. Liebe sonder.</h1>
                    <p slot="blue-text">Youth weary his high he might, heart a his ever his</p>

                    <h3 slot="green-headline">Bonan viroj por dum la kun la al mangxu hispanujo</h3>
                    <p slot="green-text">Tempor sed kasd et rebum dolor ipsum vero ipsum invidunt. Erat est sed dolores gubergren.</p>

                    <h2 slot="red-headline">Intendo cose vita con</h2>
                    <p slot="red-text">Bist ich dahinten zurück du der der deiner liebe.</p>
                </component>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Blue from './components/Blue.vue';
    import Green from './components/Green.vue';
    import Red from './components/Red.vue';

    export default {
        components: {
            appBlue: Blue,
            appGreen: Green,
            appRed: Red
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                selected: "appBlue"
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onClick: function(event, selection) {
                switch (selection) {
                    case "blue":
                        this.selected = "appBlue";
                        break;
                    case "green":
                        this.selected = "appGreen";
                        break;
                    case "red":
                        this.selected = "appRed";
                        break;
                    default:
                        this.selected = "appBlue";
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
</style>

// -- Blue.vue -----------------------------------------------------------
<template>
    <div>
        <slot name="blue-headline"></slot>
        <slot name="blue-text"></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

</script>

<style scoped>
    div {
        border: 1px solid blue;
        background-color: lightblue;
        padding: 30px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        text-align: center
    }
</style>

// -- Green.vue ----------------------------------------------------------
<template>
    <div>
        <slot name="green-headline"></slot>
        <slot name="green-text"></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

</script>

<style scoped>
    div {
        border: 1px solid green;
        background-color: lightgreen;
        padding: 30px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        text-align: center
    }
</style>

// -- Red.vue ------------------------------------------------------------
<template>
    <div>
        <slot name="red-headline"></slot>
        <slot name="red-text"></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

</script>

<style scoped>
    div {
        border: 1px solid red;
        background-color: lightcoral;
        padding: 30px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        text-align: center
    }
</style>
```

Full project-directory here on [GitHub](https://github.com/mizech/vue-js-2/tree/master/assignment08).

What do you think about my solution? What would you have done differently and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is overall very neat and clean and easily readable, I think you're ready for the next level!

---

This switch maps from one string to another:

```
switch (selection) {
    case "blue":
        this.selected = "appBlue";
        break;
    case "green":
        this.selected = "appGreen";
        break;
    case "red":
        this.selected = "appRed";
        break;
    default:
        this.selected = "appBlue";
}
```

This could either be changed into using a lookup dictionary:

```
let mappedComponents = { red: "appRed", blue: "appBlue", green: "appGreen" };
this.selected = mappedComponents[selection];
```

Or you could just skip that remapping and change the names of the components so that they directly match the `selection` value:

```
components: {
    blue: Blue,
    green: Green,
    red: Red
},

this.selected = selection;
```

---

Other notes that might not have been in your control for the assignment:

- The CSS is duplicated. You could extract `padding`, `margin` and `text-align` to a separate CSS class.
- I would recommend having just one component for all three different colors and use a property to inject its colors.